How to make a minor correction in my Schengen visa application?
I have applied for a Schengen visa for Spain for a short duration (6 days) through BLS. During the application process, there was an optional field for previous Schengen visa details, where I accidentally entered the wrong visa number. I noticed the typo only after finalizing and submitting the application, which incurred a non-refundable charge. Unfortunately, I cannot correct this information now.
The visa application that I received via email does not include any information about my previous Schengen visa.
Is it possible to correct this mistake, or do I need to cancel my appointment, fill out a new visa application with the correct details (and pay the fees again), and schedule a new visa interview?
